# Programmatically verifying x509v3 extendedKeyUsage

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, x509

**Background**

I need to programmatically verify `extendedKeyUsage` in an x509 certificate. My goal here is to make sure only `TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication` is present in `extendedKeyUsage`. I am using `OpenSSL 1.0.2p` lib on MacOS.

The following is my code for retrieving extendedKeyUsage fields:

```
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/asn1.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int verifyDeviceCertExtendedKeyUsage(){

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    auto readBytes = MyApp::FileUtil::readAllBytes("path/to/pem");

    BIO *bio_mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_puts(bio_mem, readBytes.data());
    X509 *x509 = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_mem, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ASN1_BIT_STRING *usage = static_cast<ASN1_BIT_STRING*>(X509_get_ext_d2i(x509, NID_ext_key_usage, NULL, NULL));
    if (usage && (usage->length > 0)){
        _CERTUTIL_LOG->debug("in verifyDeviceCertExtendedKeyUsage, usage->data[0]: {0:x}", (int)usage->data[0]);
    }
}
```

Also, an excerpt from output of `openssl x509 -text -noout -in path/to/pem`:

```
X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
    TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
```

**Issue**

Each time I ran my code the value of `usage->data[0]` is different which is a sign that my code is causing undefined behavior.

Note: I used a similar code to retrieve `keyUsage` fields succesfully by replacing `NID_ext_key_usage` to `NID_key_usage` in `X509_get_ext_d2i()`.

*If* my code returned correct value I would verify it by comparing to the following which is in `openssl/x509v3.h`:

```
# define XKU_SSL_SERVER          0x1
# define XKU_SSL_CLIENT          0x2
```

**Question**

Is there something wrong with my code?

How can I reliably get `extendedKeyUsage` fields and verify them?

**Update**

I have found a way, but it makes me uneasy to compare strings:

```
BIO *bio_mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(bio_mem, readBytes.data());
X509 *x509 = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_mem, NULL, NULL, NULL);

auto extIndex = X509_get_ext_by_NID(x509, NID_ext_key_usage, -1);
if(extIndex < 0){
    BIO_free(bio_mem);
    X509_free(x509);
    return ERR;
}

X509_EXTENSION *ext = X509_get_ext(x509, extIndex);

EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE *eku = static_cast<EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE*>(X509V3_EXT_d2i(ext));

for(int i = 0 ; i < sk_ASN1_OBJECT_num(eku) ; i++){
    char buffer[100] = {0}; // <--- init all elements with 0, compiler specific behavior?
    OBJ_obj2txt(buffer, sizeof(buffer), sk_ASN1_OBJECT_value(eku, i), 1);

    if(strcmp(buffer, "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") == 0 && strcmp(buffer, "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") == 0){
        BIO_free(bio_mem);
        X509_free(x509);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because X509_get_ext_d2i(..., NID_ext_key_usage, ...) returns a EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE structure (not a ASN1_BIT_STRING like for NID_key_usage). Your static_cast breaks everything and there is no usage->data field. Key usages and extended key usages don't have the same format at all, neither in the underlying X509 encoding, and in the internal OpenSSL structures.

Answer (score 1):

In openssl 1.1 it's easy once you have a X509 pointer.  You just need to use the following methods: [X509_get_extension_flags](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_get_extension_flags.html) and [X509_get_extended_key_usage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_get_extended_key_usage.html)

```
if ((X509_get_extension_flags(x509) & EXFLAG_XKUSAGE) == EXFLAG_XKUSAGE)
{
    auto const certificate_key_usage = X509_get_extended_key_usage(x509);
    if ((certificate_key_usage & (XKU_SSL_SERVER | XKU_SSL_CLIENT)) == (XKU_SSL_SERVER | XKU_SSL_CLIENT))
    {
        // has both TLS Web Server Authentication and TLS Web Client Authentication
    }
    else
    {
        // doesn't have both TLS Web Server Authentication and TLS Web Client Authentication
    }
}
```

For older versions of openssl you should be able to define the following to get the above code working:

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10100000L
#define X509_get_extension_flags(x) (x->ex_flags)
#define X509_get_extended_key_usage(x)  (x->ex_xkusage)
#endif
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately `x->ex_flags` is `0`.

Comment: I haven't had any problem with the above code so maybe the issue is something else.  Maybe it's the way you load the certificate or maybe it's the certificate itself.

Comment: You could try using something like PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX to load the PEM file.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and calling `X509_check_purpose(x, -1, -1);`  loaded the flags, maybe there is a better way to ensure that the flags are loaded.

Comment: I've never had this issue, but looking at the 1.1.1 source code for X509_get_extension_flags / X509_get_extended_key_usage they call X509_check_purpose.  So I assume you are using openssl < 1.1 so you may have to call that method to make sure the flags are filled in?